# bashでのループ処理は波括弧で囲んでも動く？

Tags: bash

Bashでのループ処理は、下記のように `do` と `done` で挟むと思うのですが、

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ./*
do
    echo $f
done
```

試しに、`{}` で囲んでも意図通りに動きました。

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./*
{
    echo $f
}
```

**実行結果:**

```
$ ./scripts2.sh 
./scripts.sh
./scripts2.sh
```

`{}` で囲んでも動いた理由がよくわからなかったのですが、こちらのコードが動く理由について教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 7):

実装経緯までは分かりませんでしたが、たしかに Bash の実装を見る限り `for` に限ってこの構文が許されていました: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y?id=9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b#n805

```
for_command:    FOR WORD newline_list DO compound_list DONE
            {
              $$ = make_for_command ($2, add_string_to_list ("\"$@\"", (WORD_LIST *)NULL), $5, word_lineno[word_top]);
              if (word_top > 0) word_top--;
            }
    |   FOR WORD newline_list '{' compound_list '}'
            {
              $$ = make_for_command ($2, add_string_to_list ("\"$@\"", (WORD_LIST *)NULL), $5, word_lineno[word_top]);
              if (word_top > 0) word_top--;
            }
（以下省略）
```

私の知る限り、この構文はドキュメントされていません。たとえば Bash のマニュアルには https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs に `for` の説明がありますが `do ... done` 形式の構文のみが書かれています。

英語版 Stack Overflow にもこの構文についての質問があり、この回答を書いている時点で存在する回答ではドキュメントは見つかっていませんでした: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22619510/5989200

Comment: 挙げられている英語版での質問に対する回答でも書かれているように、Bourne Shellがこの構文に(undocumenteで)対応しているので、それに対する互換性の為に実装されているんでしょうね。

Comment: ほんとだ `hppa2.0w-hp-hpux11.11` の `/bin/sh` でも `{ }` で動いてしまうっス。一方で `POSIX` 的には「できる」という記載がないので `dash` だとこれを拒絶してしまうっス。 `Syntax error: "{" unexpected (expecting "do")`

Comment: mksh では、`for`、`case`、`select` が歴史的 (historical) な理由で `{ }` に対応しているようです。http://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm